# app script to find next populated cell please

Tags: google-apps-script

Supposing I have a grid with cells containing different numbers and blank unpopulated Nulls.

How would I write an app script to jump straight to and activate the next populated cell (working from left to right, top to bottom)?

I've successfully been able to do this by creating a loop that searches for each possible value.

...but I'd have thought there would be a quicker way for the programme to search merely for the next populated cell within a range (anything accepted); rather than searching the range for number 1, then searching the range for number 2 ,then searching the range for number 3 etc.  (which I imagine slows the programme down a lot)

My successful (but rather long winded) formula that searches for each number within a range....

```
for(let x=1;x<=9;x++){

    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A14:I22').createTextFinder(x).matchEntireCell(true).findNext()==null){continue}

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A14:I22').createTextFinder(x).matchEntireCell(true).findNext().activate();
```

A formula which I'm looking for may look something like this even though the below fails to work...

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A14:I22').createTextFinder(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A14:I22').getActiveRange().getValues().length('1').findNext().activate());
```

or perhaps...

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A14:I22').createTextFinder().matchEntireCell(true).findNext(<>"").activate()
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange("A14:I22");
  const rr = rg.getRow();
  const rc = rg.getColumn();
  const o = [];
  const ls = rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((e, j) => {
      if (e) {
        o.push({ row: rr + i, col: rc + j, value: e });
      }
    })
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```